# передвижение объектов в разные стороны

Tags: html, css

Я наверное очень глуп, чтобы разобраться в этом. Бросил заниматься этим еще пол года назад, но захотелось испытать острых ощущений снова. Так, к чему это я..

Набросал простенький код, который можно увидеть зайдя по ссылке. Меня интересует вопрос: Почему, когда я навожу на правый квадрат, у меня происходит групповое передвижение, т.е перемещается еще и левый квадрат, тогда как при наведении на левый квадрат такого не происходит.

Даже при использовании font awesome такая проблема происходит. Похоже мне надо закреплять основы html, чувствую проблема кроется где-то там. Прошу помочь, если не трудно :-)

```css
.page1 {
  background-color: #aeb8ca;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.page1:hover {
  margin-left: 145px;
  background-color: #1c1e23;
}
.page2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #aeb8ca;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -65px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.page2:hover {
  margin-left: -70px;
  background-color: #1c1e23;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1" class="page1">A</a>
<a href="#2" class="page2">B</a>
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPyOKL)

Comment: Опубликуйте код прямо тут в виде сниппета. И, если очень нужно опубликовать ссылку на другой сайт, ее тоже нужно правильно оформить.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/uoLfqkpo/ or http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/usatc546/ - вы это хотите достичь?

Comment: да, именно то, чего я хотел. Спасибо :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что касается элемента **page2**: если у элемента не заданы или установлены в auto значения top/bottom и left/right при указанном `position: absolute`, то по умолчанию они принимают значения, как если бы стоял `position: static`. Этот элемент все еще не вырван из потока и по-прежнему привязан к **page1**.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height

Далее. Фактически, порядок элементов у вас такой: `.page1 => .page2`.
Однако из-за отрицательного отступа они меняются местами и визуально это выглядит уже так: `.page2 => .page1`.

Поскольку **на самом деле** их порядок не поменялся, то толкая с помощью положительного отступа элемент `.page1` вправо, вы невольно толкаете и следующий за ним элемент `.page2`.
Из-за того, что **визуально** элементы **поменялись местами**, это выглядит так, будто первый элемент "тянется" за вторым.

Когда вы наводите мышку на `.page2` (визуально он левый), вы с помощью **отрицательного отступа** смещаете его влево. Отрицательный отступ не влияет на `.page1` (визуально он правый), поэтому он не двигается.

---

Использована информация из этого ответа: "[position: absolute without setting top/left/bottom/right?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10244977/2486051)" с англоязычного StackOverflow.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попытаюсь вникнуть в это, чтобы в дальнейшем не было такие "легких" проблем :-)